# Parsing f element of Wavefront .OBJ file with C++

Tags: c++

Wavefront .OBJ spec spesifies that the line with face element starts with f and is followed by vertices.
If it only has vertices it looks like `f 1 2 3`. And if it has vertices and normals then its like `f 1//1 2//2 3//3`. And with textures its `f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3`. Also face does not have to be a triangle. it can be any shape. I have seen .obj files with `f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4 5/5/5 6/6/6 ....`

I have a C++ code that can handle the case of `f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3`.

```
FILE* fp;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, path, "r");
char line[256] = { 0 };
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
    sscanf_s(line,
    "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",
    &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0],
    &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1],
    &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);
 }
```

is there a sscanf_s solution i can use to handle all the other cases (only vertex, vertex + normal, more than 3 vertices)? Or should i just parse each line manually?

Comment: scanf can't handle an unlimited number of variables, no.

Comment: @user253751 But is there something that can? Cause i thing looping over it element by element is not the fastest approach.

Comment: Why do you think that?